# Android class diagram and XML

Tags: android, xml

For my dissertation I am working on an Android project, and am starting to design my class diagram.

I am thinking about how to represent my UI, and am unsure how to do so, or if I need to represent it on this diagram.

My uncertainty comes from the fact that the UI is made using XML entirely. Is it best practice to simply represent the XML classes on the class diagram in the same way I represent the java classes? Maybe with some way of showing them to be XML rather than java? Or do I leave them out all together, as they are not really classes in the same way as a java class? If I leave them out, there is no representation of my UI on the class diagram-which I guess could be ok as the class diagram represents only the object orientated structure of the code?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't show the class diagrams at all in the class diagram.

In its essence, the class diagram represents the classes in a project or application. The xml files are not coded into java classes, but have their own structure, which is then referenced in the java classes calling them.

I would different UML diagrams to represent the User Interface if necessary. The thing is, in many assignments (in a school environment), you are asked to build a class diagram also with regards to the UI being used.

The questions which may arise are the following:

1. How will you represent class attributes and methods in the diagram? These are essential to a class diagram, but on the other hand, only pertain to classes.
2. How will you structure the xml file to be represented in the diagram?

Having said that I would use a different UML diagram to represent UI.

Examples could be a [Use Case Diagram](http://indalog.ual.es/WWW/ecbs05.pdf) or a [Sequence Diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm)